# Karate: XML - CDATA print not as an xml format

Tags: karate

When I print response of the SOAP which has CDATA, it contains gt and lt as shown bellow. Can you please help to convert this to proper xml or can you help me to validate some of the value of the response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:processRequestResponse xmlns:ns="http://controller.core.xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx.com">
         <return>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
&lt;xxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx xmlns:xxx="http://xxxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/response/xyz/abc"&gt;
   &lt;Header&gt;&lt;destinationId&gt;ABC&lt;/destinationId&gt;

..............
..............
...............

   &lt;/Body&gt;
&lt;/xxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxResponse&gt;</return>
      </ns:processRequestResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one line will do the trick for you, try this:

```
* xml temp = $response//return
```